# Unable to run python Flask decorator in blueprints

Tags: python, flask-login, blueprint

I have the following snippets from a python Flask project:

permissions.py

```
def login_required(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def login_check(*args, **kwargs):
        print("I need login check!")  # --> needed to see this message
    return login_check
```

blueprints.py

```
@bp.route("/protected_page", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@permissions.login_required
def protected_page():
    return "Protected Content for logged in user"
```

When the /protected_page is met, I want to check that the user is logged in first. Here, I needed to see the printed message in the log or console. How do I achieve it?

Comment: If logout requires login, you don't need to check wheter the user is logged in, since the user can't access it without.

Comment: Yes, in order to reuse the login_required() for other APIs too. https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ (I modified the question with the protected page instead of logout example)

Comment: I don't really understand what are you trying to achieve here. Is the embedded function neccessary?

Comment: when I put all code in one file and run it then I see `I need login check!` in console/terminal - if you want to see it in log file then you would have to use module `logging` instead of `print()`

Comment: Do you see the message everytime /protected_page is called?

Comment: @nagyl It is a Flask web project, where I am trying to reuse login_required() wrapper for pages like /protected_page links. So, it is required to embed the function.